# coefficients in vglm(), orm(), polr() and clm() for ologit

Tags: r

I am doing ologit with different packages, they are `VGAM`, `rms`, `MASS` and `ordinal`, using data set `wine` from package `ordinal`.

First is `vglm()`:

```
library(VGAM)
vglmfit <- vglm(rating ~ temp * contact, data = wine, 
                family=cumulative(parallel=TRUE, reverse=TRUE))
```

The coefficients are:

```
  (Intercept):1       (Intercept):2       (Intercept):3       (Intercept):4 
      1.4112568          -1.1435551          -3.3770742          -4.9419773 
       tempwarm          contactyes tempwarm:contactyes 
      2.3212033           1.3474598           0.3595241
```

Second is `orm()`:

```
library(rms)
ormfit <- orm(rating ~ temp * contact, data = wine)
```

Coef:

```
                        Coef    S.E.   Wald Z Pr(>|Z|)
y>=2                     1.4113 0.5454  2.59  0.0097  
y>=3                    -1.1436 0.5097 -2.24  0.0248  
y>=4                    -3.3771 0.6382 -5.29  <0.0001 
y>=5                    -4.9420 0.7509 -6.58  <0.0001 
temp=warm                2.3212 0.7009  3.31  0.0009  
contact=yes              1.3475 0.6604  2.04  0.0413  
temp=warm * contact=yes  0.3595 0.9238  0.39  0.6971
```

Third, `polr`:

```
library(MASS)
polrfit <- polr(rating ~ temp * contact, method="logistic", data = wine)
```

coef:

```
Coefficients:
           tempwarm          contactyes tempwarm:contactyes 
          2.3211214           1.3474055           0.3596357 

Intercepts:
      1|2       2|3       3|4       4|5 
-1.411278  1.143507  3.377005  4.941901
```

Last, `clm()`:

```
library(ordinal)
clmfit <- clm(rating ~ temp * contact, link="logit", data = wine)
```

coef:

```
Coefficients:
           tempwarm          contactyes tempwarm:contactyes 
             2.3212              1.3475              0.3595 

Threshold coefficients:
   1|2    2|3    3|4    4|5 
-1.411  1.144  3.377  4.942
```

Besides, when `reverse=FALSE` in vglm(),

```
library(VGAM)
vglmfit <- vglm(rating ~ temp * contact, data = wine, 
                family=cumulative(parallel=TRUE, reverse=FALSE))

Coefficients:
      (Intercept):1       (Intercept):2       (Intercept):3       (Intercept):4 
         -1.4112568           1.1435551           3.3770742           4.9419773 
           tempwarm          contactyes tempwarm:contactyes 
         -2.3212033          -1.3474598          -0.3595241
```

You may notice that the coefficients in `vglm()` while `reverse=TRUE` and those in `orm()` are the same, and the ones in `polr()` and `clm()` are the same. So there are two set of coefficients, the only difference is the sign of intercepts.

And while I set `reverse=FALSE`, it does reverse the intercepts, but at the same time the parameters of variables, which I don't want.

What's the problem of that? How could I get exactly the same result? or how could I explain it?

Answer (score 2):

This is all just a matter of parametrizations. One classical way to introduce the ordered logistic regression model is to assume that there is a latent continuous response

y* = x'b + e

where e has a standard logistic distribution. Then, it is assumed that not y* itself is observed by only a discretized category y = j if y* falls between cut-offs a_j-1 and a_j. This then leads to the model equation:

logit(P(y <= j)) = a_j - x'b

Other motivations lead to similar equations but with P(y >= j) and/or a_j + x'b. This just leads to switches in the signs of the a and/or b coefficients that you observe in the different implementations. The corresponding models and predictions are equivalent, of course. Which interpretation you find easier is mostly a matter of taste.