# Linear regression with ordinal variable

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, interaction, ordinal

I have five cognitive variables (memory, cognitive flexibility, critical thinking, verbal, and attention)  and one ordinal variable (adversity scores from 1-10). I have cortical thickness as my outcome variable (or dependent variable).

I was wondering how I can set up my regression?

I was thinking to do this:

```
lm(cortical_thickness ~ memory + cognitive_flexibility + critical_thinking + verbal + attention + adversity_score)
```

or should I set it up like this instead:

```
lm(cortical_thickness ~ (memory + cognitive_flexibility + critical_thinking + verbal + attention)* adversity_score)
```

Comment: Your second example is modelling something very different as you are introducing an interaction term, which I dont think is what you want

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion your question is a more statistical question. And it is not as trivial as it sounds. The question is how to deal with ordinal predictors in the context of multiple linear regression.
The simple answer is treat your 10 scaled ordinal predictor as a continuous variable and then I would use:

`model1 <- lm(cortical_thickness ~ memory + cognitive_flexibility + critical_thinking + verbal + attention + adversity_score, data=yourdataset)`

How to model depends strong on your data. Therefore I think you should ask this question with your data here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Although you can run `lm`, ordinal regression models do not satisfy the assumptions of linear regression so model comparisons and other tests won't be valid.

R does have ordinal regression functions which you may wish to try. Four such packages are listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29880383/coefficients-in-vglm-orm-polr-and-clm-for-ologit).

Regarding which model to use, run both models and compare them.  If fm1 and fm2 are the two models then

```
anova(fm1, fm2)
```

will compare them and works for at least clm and polr.  See `?clm` in ordinal package or `?polr` in the MASS package for examples including the use of `anova`.